# Jquery - Delay mouseout event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, mouseout

Is there a way to make jQuery wait a certain about amount of time before `mouseout` event is fired?

It is firing too early at the moment and I'd prefer to wait 500ms before it evaluates the mouse out. An example of the code I'm using below.

```
$('.under-construction',this).bind({
    mousemove: function(e) {
        setToolTipPosition(this,e);
        css({'cursor' : 'crosshair' });
    },
    mouseover: function() {
        $c('show!');
        showUnderConstruction();
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        $c('hide!');
        hideUnderConstruction();
    },
    click: function() {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Is there a jQuery way to do this or will I have to do it myself?

Comment: showUnderConstruction().delay(500);
hideUnderConstruction().delay(500);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split the logic inside the `mouseout` into another function. in the `mouseout` even call this function with a `setTimeout("myMouseOut", 500)`. And you can combine the `mouseover` event with a `clearTimeout()` to reset the timer if the user moves into a new element.

Answer (score 5):

You could always wrap your logic in a `setTimeout()` function.

```
mouseout: function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $c('hide!');
    hideUnderConstruction();
  }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might check out the [hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) lets you define some vars that help with mouseenter/out interactions